# Update Firebase-Storage Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

Can someone please explain to me how to update and image with nodejs in firebase-storage/google-cloud-storage?

Im able to replace it but i have no idea how to update it.

```
const uploadImage = (image) => {
  const file = bucket.file('path/to/file/image.jpg').createWriteStream({
    metadata: { contentType: 'image/jpeg' },
  });
  image.body.pipe(file);
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to update a part of an image object already in GCS? That level of granularity is not supported in GCS. You update an existing obejct by overwriting it. Here's a list of operations supported by the object resource: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#methods

Comment: no, i want to update the whole image / i want to replace it with a different (new) image. the only problem i have right now is => i want to keep the "createdAt" date. do i have to fetch the date and redefine it on the new image or is there a different method that just replaces the image and keeps everything else?

Comment: It looks like creation time is a non-editable metadata field: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#fixed. But you can set creation time as a custom metadata field, and see if it survives the object overwrite. If that doesn't work you can always read the creation time of the existing object (which should be a cheap operation), and then pass it along with the new upload.

Comment: thx a lot, custom metadata works just fine.